# Draw a border around an oval picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I've an oval picturebox (Code below). I want to add a border around the picturebox. I allready tried to add a second rect but this only made my region smaller. Is there any way to make a border?

```
using System; 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class OvalPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public OvalPictureBox()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));

            this.Region = new Region(gp);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // OvalPictureBox
        // 
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I figured it out. I just draw an ellipse in the picturebox.

```
float penWidth = 5F;
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(242, 141, 1), penWidth);
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 0), new 
SizeF((float)(portraitPicture.Width - 1), portraitPicture.Height - 1)));
myPen.Dispose();
```

Is there a cleaner or better way? Or is this the best way?

Comment: This is the solution I gave you :)

Comment: Oh so i did miss understand you haha :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw ellipse that is bigger than the one you already have. But this ellipse should be drawn first, otherwise it would cover the other ellipse.

How much should it be bigger? Border width :)

Comment: If i use your awnser it seems like i just have a 5px thick picture. What am i doing wrong?

I would like one with a thickness of 5px.

Comment: So you should draw this ellipse 10 px bigger.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't matter when i draw the ellipse, it just makes my Region like a 5px thick circle